# Compiling C error - CS50 course - week 1 - Linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation, cs50

i'm trying to compile a simple code by following the steps that the professor made but I have this issue

```
cc     calculator.c   -o calculator
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccznJMZB.o: in function `main':
calculator.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `get_int'
/usr/bin/ld: calculator.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `get_int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: calculator] Error 1
```

I'm using Linux mint btw, already had problems installing cs50 library but that's done. I'm happy to get a new error tho, but I need to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to link against the CS50 libraries, which contain the special CS50-only functions like `get_int()`.

Comment: Do you know the name of the cs50 library you installed, and where you put it?

Comment: It is also worth mentioning, that you must include the header (cs50.h) not the implementation file (cs50.c). If you do `#include "cs50.c"` you will also get compilation and/or linker errors.

Comment: yes, because both the compiler and the linker are complaining.

Comment: I do have the library on my code (#include <cs50.h> and also tried with the " " instead of <>). Not using the cs50.c at all. But since I had some issues to install it, maybe it's not working good because of that. But it's weird because I had another error that said "cs50.h not found" or something like that, but it was clear that I did not had that library. Now that error disappear (because I installed it) but I'm still having this one. Should I purge the cs50 and install it again? how could I do it successfully in linux mint? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/

> To use these functions, make sure to include `#include <cs50.h>` atop your file and compile with the `-lcs50` flag.

`#include <cs50.h>` requires the header file `cs50.h` to be in the include path of your compiler.

`#include "cs50.h"` expects the header file `cs50.h` to be in the same directory as your `.c`file.

The link above also tells you how to install the library:

```bash
$ curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/cs50/repo/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo apt install libcs50
```

> Troubleshooting
>
> If when compiling your program, you see:
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcs50:
> Add export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib to your .bashrc.
>
> fatal error: 'cs50.h' file not found:
> Add export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include to your .bashrc.
>
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory:
> Add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib to your .bashrc.